# How To SetDataSouce on Crystal Report WIth Multiple Procedures

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

[image]

Now I am Trying to set the Report Data Source from C# Code on the Asp Page.
Using DataSet that had Tables as for Both Procedure added in the report.

the code is as follows

```
                strPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Reports/") + RptName + ".rpt";
                rptDoc.Load(strPath);
                DataSet DS = new DataSet();
                DS = objCommon.FillDataSetMTG(SqlConn, "USP_Report_ExecProcs", Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["Id"]), "JobEntryId");
                rptDoc.SetDataSource(DS);
```

But report isnt taking the data.
any suggestions ?

Comment: i wanna do it without using subreports...if possible

Comment: Shouldn't tables' names contained in DataSet match Database Fields names? Another way could be to set the two tables like this `rptDoc.Database.Tables[0].SetDataSource(dataTableJobCardDet);` `rptDoc.Database.Tables[1].SetDataSource(dataTableJobCard);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set different datasource for each Tables within the Report, try this one, you must call both "USP_Report_JobCardDet" and "USP_Report_JobCard" stored procedure

```
            strPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Reports/") + RptName + ".rpt";
            rptDoc.Load(strPath);

            DataSet DS1 = new DataSet();
            DS1 = objCommon.FillDataSetMTG(SqlConn, "USP_Report_JobCardDet", Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["Id"]), "JobEntryId");
            rptDoc.Tables["USP_Report_JobCardDet"].SetDataSource(DS1);

            DataSet DS2 = new DataSet();
            DS2 = objCommon.FillDataSetMTG(SqlConn, "USP_Report_JobCard", Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["Id"]), "JobEntryId");
            rptDoc.Tables["USP_Report_JobCard"].SetDataSource(DS2);
```

Answer (score 1):

add

`rptDoc.Refresh();`

If data are properly acquired